# Fastest way to find path from top left to bottom right of a matrix

Tags: algorithm

Say we have an `n` x `m` matrix with the cells either empty or full. The top left and bottom right cells are both empty. You can move up, down, left, or right. What is the fastest method to see if a path of length `<= T` of empty cells connects the top left and bottom right corner? I've tried both DFS and BFS with a matrix keeping track of how long it took to get to a particular cell, but both methods were too slow.

EDIT: I don't have access to the code anymore, but here's the pseudocode of what I did.

```
def find_path(grid, T):
    visited = array(grid.dims)
    visited.fill(0)
    stack = []
    stack.append((0, 0, T))
    while len(queue) > 0:
        pos = stack.pop()
        if pos[0] == len(grid) and pos[1] == len(grid[0]):
            return True
        if pos[2] > 0:
            if pos[0] < len(grid)-1 and grid[pos[0]+1][pos[1]] == empty and visited[pos[0]+1][pos[1]] < T-1:
                visited[pos[0]+1][pos[1]] = T-1
                stack.append(pos[0]+1, pos[1], T-1)
            {same for right, left, up}
    return False
```

Comment: Both of those methods should be very fast.  You must have done something wrong in the implementation.  Which one is faster depends on the contents of the matrix, but for randomized inputs, DFS will be a little faster on average, but BFS will find the shortest path.

Comment: That's what I was thinking! The implementation for both is pretty simple, and I even implemented DFS both recursively and iteratively, but time limit exceeded on the same subset of test cases.

Comment: If you post the simplest implementation, folks here will be happy to show you where it's broken.  Usually a TLE for this kind of problem comes from a failure to track and avoid previously visited cells.

Comment: DFS should work well enough, add your code here so that the issue can be addressed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the visited array, but "keeping track of how long it took to get to a particular cell" is not going to work with DFS, and is unnecessary with BFS.  Probably the problems with your real code are in there somewhere.

The straightforward way to solve this is with a level-by-level BFS, like (in similar pseudocode):

```
def hasPath(grid,T):
    gridcopy = copy(grid)
    level=[(0,0)]
    for pathlen in 1..T-1:
       # Invariant: the positions in level are at path length pathlen
       nextlevel=[]
       for (x,y) in level:
           # each valid direction is north plus maybe southwest and maybe southeast
           for sw in 0..1, se in 0..1:
               testx = x-sw+se
               testy = y-1+sw+se
               if testx >= 0 and 
                  testy >= 0 and 
                  testx < grid.width and 
                  testy < grid.height and
                  gridcopy[testy][testx] == empty:
                  
                  if testx==grid.width-1 and testy==grid.height-1
                       return True
                  nextlevel.append((testx,testy))
                  gridcopy[testy][testx] = blocked
       level = nextlevel
    return false
```

Comment: why "keeping track of how long it took to get to a particular cell" is not going to work with DFS? In DFS for an invalid path you might get to cell (x, y) with 4 steps remaining, but on a new path, you still want to consider cell (x, y) if you have more than 4 steps remaining.

Comment: Because with DFS you can find a shorter path to a given cell after you find the first one, which means you'd have to write a shorter length for that cell and search from there *again*.  With BFS you always find the shortest path first, so you don't have that problem.